# Portable conversion from unsigned to signed in C++

Tags: c++, types, casting, type-conversion

I have `std::vector<unsigned short int> vals` for which I need to invert the order of the bytes (assume 2) and store them as `short int`. I was doing it as:

```
std::vector<short int> result;
for(unsigned short int& x : vals) {
    x = ((x << 8) | (x >> 8));
    result.push_back(static_cast<short int>(x));
}
```

Reading online, I find that `static_cast` has implementation-defined behavior. I also found `std::bit_cast`, which preserves the bits and interprets them in the new type.

Does that mean that using `std::bit_cast<short int>(x)` above should be preferred over `static_cast`?

I tried, and both give the same results for me. Is it correct to assume that `bit_cast` will give the same results to anyone else using my code, while `static_cast` could give them different results?

Comment: The type of `result` should be `std::vector<unsigned short>`. There is no way for a bit from the middle of a value to become the sign bit for a signed type.

Comment: @AlanBirtles `x` is `unsigned short int` not `short int`

Comment: @PeteBecker How come? That is exactly what happens in the code from my question. The middle bit becomes the sign bit of the signed type.

Comment: what if the unsigned short is greater than the limit of short int?

Comment: just a side comment - why do you modify the source data? You should usually declare a by ref iteration variable `const`.

Comment: @user17004502 -- whoops, careless editing. Yes, that's what happens. But it's not a logical thing to do. Unless you're deep into hardware hacking, bit manipulation should be done on unsigned types. That way, bits are bits, with none having any special significance.

Comment: @foragerDev Which `unsigned short`? The original one, or the result after swapping the byte order? I just have a bunch of `short int` in a binary file in big-endian; I just want to read them as little-endian. If the `unsigned short` MSB is 1, I just want the signed representation of those bits, nothing else.

Comment: @PeteBecker That is exactly the reason why I do the bit manipulation with `unsigned short` and just at the end, when all I want is the `short` from those bits I want to cast it to `short int`. I don't know if it makes sense; it is a bit difficult to explain in a comment.

Comment: @user17004502 -- until recently, there were three different ways that C compilers could represent signed integer types: sign-magnitude, ones-complement, and twos-complement (the choice was usually made to match the target hardware). In all cases, the high bit indicated the sign. The actual value, of course, depended on the rest of the bits, and the meaning of those bits was determined by the representation. The same bit pattern meant three different things in those three different representations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle bytes - you should not convert them to a non byte type (especially not `short int` and friends because they does not need to be 16 bits exactly).
You should read the bytes as an array of `char` or `std::byte`. Then you can swap those values in safe and portable manner.
Converting those bytes to a numeric type is not doable in portable way.